# SQL query LEFT JOIN issue (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, null, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I have 2 tables

`SCHOOLS` (ID, SCHOOL_NAME, CITY_ID)
`STUDENTS` (ID, STUDENT_NAME, SCHOOL_ID).

I want to list schools in a particular city along with the student count (School Name| Student Count)

One way to do this is to have co-related subquery -

```
select sh.school_name, 
       (select count(*) 
          from student 
         where school_id = sh.id) as student_count 
 from schools sh 
where sh.city_id = 1
```

But since co-related queries are not recommended, I want to avoid that & I tried a group by -

```
   select sh.school_name, 
          count(st.school_id) as student_count 
     from schools sh 
left join students st on sh.id = st.school_id 
    where sh.city_id = 1 
 group by st.school_id
```

Now this works only if the student count for a school is > 0. So i m guessing the left join concept is not working, meaning if any schools that has no students should be listed as student_count=0, but that is not happening. The interesting thing is - i do see "one" record with student_count = 0, but thats about it.

Anything wrong in my LEFT JOIN query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT sh.id,
          sh.school_name, 
          COUNT(st.school_id) as student_count 
     FROM SCHOOLS sh 
LEFT JOIN STUDENTS st on sh.id = st.school_id  
    WHERE sh.city_id = 1 
 GROUP BY sh.id, sh.school_name
```

Because of using the LEFT JOIN, references to `st` will be NULL if there are no students associated with the school.  COUNT doesn't count NULL values, so if there are no students associated then `student_count` will be zero.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried your solution, but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @user310525: Can you provide some data so I can test?  A LEFT JOIN ensures that schools with zero student counts will not be missing from the list.  Are you sure there are schools with zero counts in the `city_id` specified?

Comment: yea i m sure because the co-related query is returning the desired results (total rows return=60, with students greater than 0 = 6 rows). But group_by query returns 6 + 1 rows. That 1 row is the first school record with student = 0.

Comment: @user310525: I was just about to post my CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements... =)

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by sh.id instead of st.school_id